# Bootstrap 3 columns do not fill the whole container

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid, row

I am new to Bootstrap. In the following code snipped, first row does not completely fill out the container, but the second row (being in a row a class) does fill the whole container. So, if you want to fill the whole container, you have to always nest things into a "".

```
    <div class="container" style="background:#00f">
    <!--<div class="row" style="background-color: #2fa4e7">-->
        <div class="col-xs-2" style="background-color: red">
            col
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            col
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            col
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            col
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            col
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2" style="background-color: red">
            col
        </div>
    <!--</div>-->

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12" style="background-color: red">
            col
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you add the following to your css, then "row" starts to behave like the columns:

```
.row {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

I was wondering why, in other words, why row has got negative margins by default?

Comment: Please read [Bootstrap Grid System](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Comment: I have already done this. it says: "... Columns create gutters (gaps between column content) via padding. That padding is offset in rows for the first and last column via negative margin on .rows. ...", but why? In my view, first column does not need a gutter on the left and last column does not need a gutter on the right side, right?

Answer (score 0):

You may try to remove the padding for the whole container:

```
.container {
        padding-left: 0px  !important;
        padding-right: 0px !important;
}
.container .row {
        margin-left: 0px !important;
        margin-right: 0px !important;
}
```

The snippet:

```css
.container {
  padding-left: 0px  !important;
  padding-right: 0px !important;
}
.container .row {
  margin-left: 0px !important;
  margin-right: 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container" style="background:#00f">
    <!--<div class="row" style="background-color: #2fa4e7">-->
    <div class="col-xs-2" style="background-color: red">
        col
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        col
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        col
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        col
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        col
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2" style="background-color: red">
        col
    </div>
    <!--</div>-->

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12" style="background-color: red">
            col
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, true, but don't you think that since row is inside the container, it should behave like a 'col-xx-12', right? but it does not, why? In other words, why 'row' is given negative margins? When I set the margin to zero, then it behaves like a col-xx-12.

Comment: @BehzadPirvali The margins and padding are defined by default. A row and a set of 6 col-xs-2 are two different, let me use, objects. Do you agree?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure, I can agree. container is like a box, when you put things in a box, you expect that it stays in the box. In other words, default margins and padding are all good, and 'row' should violate them by having a negative margin, right?